# Is there a way to express the function application operator/function with Hana?

Tags: c++, haskell, functional-programming, boost-hana, combinatory-logic

### My question

I'm referring to a function which does essentially the following (modulo `const`, `&`, perfect forwarding, or whatever is appropriate):

```cpp
auto constexpr dollar = [](auto f, auto x){ return f(x); }; // Why calling it "dollar"? Keep reading...
```

Is such a function expressable only via Boost.Hana?

### Why did I think of it?

In Haskell, such a function exists, and it's called `($)` (`$` in infix form), and its definition is the following ([source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#%24))

```hs
($) :: forall r a (b :: TYPE r). (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $ x =  f x
```

and you could write the second line simply as either of the following

```hs
(f $) = f
($) f = f
```

where the second form makes it apparent that `($)` is essentially the same as the [`id` (the identity function)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#id),

```hs
id :: a -> a
id x = x
```

just with a signature that enforces that the first argument be of function type `a -> b`.

Indeed, applying `f` to `x` in Haskell can be done also by writing this

```hs
f `id` x
```

i.e. using `` `id` `` instead of `$`.¹

### How is that related to Hana?

Since Hana *does* offer an `id` function, I was wondering if that (maybe together with something else) can be used to define a function application utility without manually writing the lambda at the top of this post.

### The difficult part

The hard part here is that when you write `` f `id` x `` in Haskell, there's not much really a point in arguing on whether you're passing 1 or 2 arguments to `id`, because all functions are curried by default.

That's not true in C++. For instance I can do this:

```cpp
#include <boost/hana/functional/id.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using boost::hana::id;
int main() {
    auto plus1 = [](int x){ return x + 1; };
    std::cout << id(plus1)(3) << std::endl; // prints 4
}
```

which looks a lot like `id` is curried and is being given two inputs one after the other rather than together, but that's not true. It's just that `id(plus1)` is returning `plus1`, which is fed with `3`. I don't know how to get *the following* (which would be equivalent to `` plus1 `id` 3 `` or `id plus1 3` in Haskell) work:

```cpp
    std::cout << id(plus1, 3) << std::endl; // doesn't even compile obviously
```

### The true origin of the puzzle

After reading [*To Mock a Mockingbird*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Mock_a_Mockingbird), I wondered: "How do I implement the Thrush in C++ only with Boost.Hana?" (And the Thrush is the `boost::hana::flip`ped version of the function application operator.)

---

¹In reality it's not exactly the same if want to write chains of applications, as the two operators have different associativity, so `` f $ g $ x == f `id` (g `id` x) ``, but this is not relevant to the question, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

#### Eureka!

Here's a oneliner that seems to be a very succint solution:

```cpp
constexpr auto identity = overload(id, apply);
```

where only Hana functions are used, namely

```cpp
using boost::hana::apply;
using boost::hana::id;
using boost::hana::overload;
```

I haven't tested it thoroughly, but at least for some simple case it seems to work:

```cpp
assert(21 == identity(21));
assert(21 == identity(times3, 7));
assert(21 == identity(times3)(7));
```

Having defined `identity` like above, the `thrush` is easy to implement:

```cpp
constexpr auto thrush = curry<2>(flip(identity));

assert(21 == thrush(7, times3));
assert(21 == thrush(7)(times3));
```

([Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/vrT4odoaW))

---

The `identity` function defined above, is very similar to this, modulo perfect forwarding and other details (which might become important when one tries to `apply` member functions),

```cpp
constexpr auto identity = [](auto const& x, auto const&... xs) {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(xs) == 0) {
        return x;
    } else {
        return x(xs...);
    }
};
```